# How can the screen view be moved to the cursor cell in Google Sheets – s.getRange(s.getCurrentCell().getA1Notation())?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, cursor

With `s.getRange(s.getCurrentCell().getA1Notation())` there seems to be no move of the screen view because the cell is already active. Is it still possible to move the view without activating a different cell before?

If a different cell than the currently active cell is activated, the screen view moves to the cell. If the already active cell is activated with getRange(), no move occurs. The move is relevant, for example, if you have scrolled and then set up a filter using a macro, since cell A2 should then be activated with screen move. This seems not to work if A2 is active before the macro is started.

So if A2 is active before the macro start, this works:

```
s.getRange('A1').activate();
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
s.getRange('A2').activate();
```

and this does not cause any moving of the screen:

```
s.getRange('A2').activate();
```

When I have checked the filter results by scrolling and empty the filter or set up a new filter criterion, A2 is activated because the filter checks from top to bottom. When scrolling, the active cell is often A2, so there is no screen movement when using the filter macros.

Comment: Why don't you just specify the cell you want to edit , eg : getRange('A2')

Comment: The cell should not be edited, it is about the screen move to the active cell.

Comment: Why do you wanna move the screen to the active cell ? What is exactly your goal ?

Comment: @user8652270 I would assume this happens because of a guard that checks if the active cell is the same as requested and exits early. Needs testing, though, so if I have anything of substance, will post here.

Comment: Why don't you want to do two `activate()` calls? If the first script example works, then why is this not suitable for your needs? It would be important to know *why* you want to do this as there may be a different approach which will fit your needs.

Comment: It is not required, but when using several filter macros for single columns , several jumps are made. If it is possible to do without it, it looks more fluid.

Comment: To directly answer your question ` Is it still possible to move the view without activating a different cell before?` - no, this isn't possible as there are no methods which do this. If the cell is already active, then you can only move the view by running something akin to your first code snippet.